# Failed to call CORS web service from jquery and plain javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, cors

I am trying to access [a public web service provided by USGS](http://waterservices.usgs.gov/rest/IV-Service.html#CORS). According to the web page, they support `CORS`, and even provided a `JQuery` example (one thing worth to mention is that the example sets no header), but I tried everything and so far have no luck. There are lots of posts about `cross-domain ajax` and `CORS` on stackoverflow, but none has helped so far.

I tried both plain `XMLHttpRequest` and `JQuery`, with and without various headers, nothing worked. The plain one give back `status` code 0, which I believe it is an indicator that the request was blocked somewhere.

Anybody had successful experience with `javascript CORS`, either plain or with jquery?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callWebService() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                } else {
                    alert(xmlhttp.status);
                }
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=json&sites=01646500&parameterCd=00060", true);
        //xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept","text/plain");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, x-requested-by, Content-Type");
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "604800");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function callWebServiceWithJQuery() {
        $(document).ajaxError(
        function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
            alert('[event:' + objToString(event) + '], [jqXHR:' + objToString(jqXHR) + '], [ajaxSettings:' + objToString(ajaxSettings) + '], [thrownError:' + objToString(thrownError) + '])');
        });
        $.ajax({
            /*beforeSend: function (request) {
                request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, x-requested-by, Content-Type");
                request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
                request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "604800");
            },*/
            url: "http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=json&sites=01646500&parameterCd=00060",
            dataType:'json',
            data:'',

            success: function(response) {
                alert("succ");
                alert(response); 
            },
            error: function(a,b,c) {
                alert("err");
                alert(a); 
                alert(b); 
                alert(c); 
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<button onclick="callWebService();">Click me</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have to set any headers. The server does that. Provide us with the response headers from the server that contains those headers so we can confirm that you are following the CORS policy set by said server.

Comment: @KevinB, thanks for replying, Quentin's answer below solved the problem. Obviously you are right about the header. The key for me was that return false. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems.

## Leaving the page

You are triggering the Ajax request in response to a submit button being clicked.

Immediately after sending the request, the form submits and you leave the page, which causes the browser to abort the Ajax request.

The usual way to prevent the form from submitting when you are using an `onclick` attribute is to `return false;` from it. Now we are in the 21st century, however, I urge you to learn about [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and move on from `onclick`.

## Making a non-simple request

You are setting a bunch of custom request headers. These all require that the browser makes a [pre-flight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) to ask permission to make a cross-domain Ajax request with custom headers. The server doesn't grant permission for that. Don't set the custom request headers.

`X-Requested-With` is a non-standard (albeit common) hack to let a server send different content based on if the request is from Ajax or not (typically switching between JSON and an HTML document, something better suited to the `Accept` header). It isn't needed here. Don't set it.

`Access-Control-Allow-etc` are **response** headers. The server you are making the request to must respond with them to tell the browser that your site is allowed to use Ajax to access it. You can't set them on the client, it would be ridiculous for a site to grant itself permission to access a different site. Don't try to set these.

Comment: with the latest jquery, everything is fine, but my drupal site uses jquery 1.3.4 (which I cannot change), and instead of sending get, jquery sends an options request... any way to force a get?

Comment: That's the preflight again. Figure out what about jQuery 1.3 (which is **ancient** and really shouldn't be used for new development) is making it a non-simple request and then fix that.